# CSS3: parent element has hover, animated element inside

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```
<div style="width: 310px; height: 160px; position: relative;" class="feature-box">                          
    <a href="" style="display: block; width: 310px; height: 160px; position: relative;">
        <div class="feature-box-link">My Service</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is `CSS3 transition` the `div` within the `a` ... so when you `hover` over `feature-box a:hover` the `.feature-box-link` animates:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
line-height: 19px;
```

to:

```
line-height: 50px;
background: #FF9E00;
background: rgba(255, 158, 0, 0.75); 
height: 40px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQy34/)

```
.feature-box a .feature-box-link {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    line-height: 19px;
}

.feature-box a:hover .feature-box-link  {
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #FF9E00;
    background: rgba(255, 158, 0, 0.75);
    height: 40px;
}
```